# Mozilla Extension error

Tags: xml, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm getting this error

```
Timestamp: 4/2/12 11:56:36 AM
Error: uncaught exception: 
   [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 
   (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMWindow.localStorage]"  
   nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  
   location: "JS frame :: chrome://myextension/content/users.js 
   :: startFBP :: line 6"  data: no]
```

**My files:**

chrome.manifest

```
content myextension chrome/content/
content myextension chrome/content/ contentaccessible=yes
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://myextension/content/tracker.xul
```

install.rdf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>firefox@myextension.fourbananas</em:id>
    <em:version>2.0</em:version>
    <em:type>2</em:type>

    <!-- Target Application this extension can install into, 
         with minimum and maximum supported versions. --> 
    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>13.0.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>

    <!-- Front End MetaData -->
    <em:name>myextension</em:name>
    <em:description>My Extension! Una extensión que te permite añadir funciones únicas a tus redes sociales</em:description>
    <em:creator>Four Bananas</em:creator>
    <em:homepageURL>http://myextension.me/</em:homepageURL>
  </Description>      
</RDF>
```

Comment: Please do check this `location: "JS frame :: chrome://myextension/content/users.js `

Comment: There is something wrong at line no 6 in the JS page. If you think some component problem then try to update your FF & check it out.

Comment: The exception clearly says that the error is in file `users.js`, function `startFBP`. So why are you quoting `install.rdf` and `chrome.manifest` that are entirely unrelated to the problem instead of quoting the code where the error happens? Also, please mention in which context this code runs - the browser window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though there is almost no useful information in the question, the exception indicates that there is an error accessing `window.localStorage`. My psychic powers tell me that you are attempting to access `window.localStorage` in a document loaded from `chrome://`, probably the browser window's XUL document. This will not work: `localStorage` is always bound to a server host name, meaning that you only have it for documents loaded from `http://`.

In an extension you can use different mechanisms to store data persistently, most common being [preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences).